# Search for particular commits

Tags: git

I'm working on a large project that mixes C++ code and HTML template files.

I learnt today that I was supposed to merge the changes I made to the C++ files (*and only those*) on another branch, but as you might guess: I can't remember all the commits I did.

Is there a way for me to search, through the git history, all the commits that match **all these criteria** ?

- Are written by me
- Are located between commit `A` and commit `B`
- Contain changes to `.cpp`, `.c` or `.h` files (those are located in a particular sub-directory if that helps).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do that:

To search commits matching a particular author, you can use the `--author` option:

```
git log --author=ereOn
```

To search commits from commit `A` to `B`, use the `A..B` form:

```
git log 9223253452..HEAD
```

Finally, to only care about commits that concern specific files or paths:

```
git log -- path_or_file
```

The `--` is used to indicate the end of the optional arguments and the beginning of the positional arguments.

All combined, that gives:

```
git log --author=ereOn 9223a6d916c034345..HEAD -- cpp_folder/*
```

Which works like a charm :)

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it's the best answer that's been posted!

Comment: @WillVousden: Can only do that in 2 days :)

Comment: could you explain this a little?

Comment: @JKirchartz: Sure. I edited my answer to add the details about each option.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `git log`, running `git log --stat` will show a lot of the details you're looking for, you could search by piping it to grep like `git log --stat | grep searchterm`, but that will only give you lines with your search term.

You can limit it to author with this flag `--author "your name"`

On my machine `git log`'s output is run through vim/less, with that you can search the log with vim's search command like `/searchterm`, to find all occurrences of the term, to go to the next one hit `n` to go to the previous hit `N`

Check out the man page for [`git log`](http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+git-log)